# Mostrar el siguiente ID

Tags: sql, angular

tengo un campo Auto_Increment en mi base de datos que se llama historia, tengo un formulario en el cual quiero mostrar cual va a ser el siguiente historia que se va a insertar, supongo que solo debo obtener el último y sumarle uno, pero como puedo hacerlo en angular?

El campo en el que se debe mostrar la id es en historia

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT MAX(historia)+1 as id FROM pacientes
```

Si tiro el siguiente comando en mi mysql me lo saca bien, como puedo añadirlo a mi API y llamarlo desde ahi?

Comment: ¡Cuidado con eso! Imagina dos usuarios que quieren hacer esa operación a la vez: los dos verán el mismo valor para ese campo pero realmente sólo uso de los dos obtendrá ese número en su nuevo registro. Ese campo debería estar vacío y rellenarse sólo cuando ya se ha creado el campo

Comment: @PabloLozano ya.. pero bueno es lo que necesito hacer

Comment: ¿Porqué en lugar del siguiente id de la tabla no haces un conteo de los registros por seguridad social? Es decir...  fulanito a lleva 3 registros su siguiente es el 4... fulanito b lleva 0 su siguiente es 1... y así.... inclusive ya podrías contar como quieras... por año o por mes...